# TFS Build continuous integration with multiple branches

Tags: msbuild

In my TFS solution, I have two branches `Main` and `Dev`. We have four different hosting environments `Dev`, `ITST`, `QA` and `Prod`, and a different build script for each environment.

Whenever there is a check-in, a build runs and deploys the solution to the `Dev` environment. However, it is only building our `Main` branch and not whatever is checked into the `Dev` branch.

For the `Dev` build script, how would I go about specifying which branch to build? I've already tried configuring the Source Settings, but when I specified the `Dev` branch for the Source Control Folder, I kept getting errors related to the mappings.

### Update

Here is the error I'm getting: `There is no working folder mapping for $/DLS/Application/P1/P1.sln`

Comment: What are the mapping errors?

Comment: @MikeCheel I updated the post with my error.

Comment: Open the build def and verify the workspace mappings.

Comment: Also, what version of TFS are you using?

Comment: @MikeCheel We are using TFS2013. Here are my mappings:

1) Status: Active - Source Control Folder: $/DLS/Application/DEV - Build Agent Folder: $(SourceDir)\DLS
2) Status: Cloaked - Source Control Folder: $/DLS/Application/DEV/Drops - Build Agent Folder: [EMPTY]

Comment: Here is a coincidence. I just had to make some new build defs today and I just got the same error a second ago. In my case the problem is not the mappings but the solution under items to build is pointing the solution but in the wrong branch.

Comment: @MikeCheel That was the problem! It was building the solution in my Main branch rather than my Dev branch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like TFS is looking for:

> $/DLS/Application/P1/P1.sln

You have it mapped to:

> $/DLS/Application/DEV

Try changing the 'Active' mapping to something like:

> $/DLS/Application

Or

> $/DLS/Application/P1